# android:Can we use XML layout for popup window insted of dynamic?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Can we use XML layout for popup window insted of dynamic? please give me a example

Thanks a lot...

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. What is it you are trying to ask?

Comment: What kind of popup,what are you trying to do?

Comment: I am trying to ask can we define layout view which define in layout folder as mylayout.xml and which we load in pop up Dialog box instead of create a new layout. can we directly call that xml file as resource ??

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
   public class MyLoadingDialog extends Dialog {

    public MyLoadingDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.mylayoutfile);
    } 
}
```